# Private key access to ssh refused through putty

Tags: virtualbox, putty, vagrant

I am studying about VM and vagrant.

I am getting network refuse error when I am trying to access to ssh through putty.

I already installed putty, puttygen, vagrant and virtualbox.
and I am using window 7 32bit.

What I did was...

1. Using puttygen and go to .vagrant.d folder to select insecure_private_key.
2. I create the private key which name has "putty_key"
3. go to Putty: Connection ->Data and I put the "vagrant" as Auto-login usename
4. go to connection ->ssh->auth  and I select the "putty_key" as private key file for authentication.
5. then i go back to session 
   Host name(or IP address) : localhost
   part: 2222
   Saved session: vagrant 
   then I saved setting.

When I double click "vagrant"
error window was popped up

"Network error: Connection refused"

I am not really sure that reason that I am getting this error.

does anybody know that solution about this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Connection refused" usually means that there is no listening socket at the target port.  Verify that you have an SSH server listening on port 2222, and verify that it is bound at least to the loopback interface.

To do so, from a command prompt: `netstat -p tcp -a -n` and look for a line with the state `LISTENING`, and a *local address* of something that ends with `:2222`

Comment: Another question , do i need to run the vagrant before using the putty to access it ?

Comment: From a command prompt: `netstat -p tcp -a -n` and look for a line with the state "LISTENING", and a "local address" of something that ends with ":2222".  And yes, of course the server must be running before you may connect to it.  What magic could allow you to connect to a server that is not running?

Comment: I fix the problem.(i am not really sure this is right way to do it or not..) I thk, I forgot run the vagrant, so there was not way to find port 2222.